# How to enable flash in Selenium python firefox

Tags: python, selenium, flash, firefox

When I open firefox it has Flash installed in it but when I open it through selenium That version of firefox has not Flash in it. How to enable flash in selenium . 
This is the test code I am working with :

```
firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so','true')
b = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile, executable_path=r"C:\\Program Files\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\geckodriver.exe")
b.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Comment: There are two ways to do that, 1. Create a profile manually with flash add-on like Adobe, etc. Then load it with selenium driver. 2. Download flash plugin installer and add while launch the browser.

Comment: @Murthi Thankyou for the help I tired first one and googled a lot. I am able to open firefox with flash. but it is disabled. How can I Activate in code. So that firefox lunch with Flash with status "Always activate"

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the following to your current code:

`firefoxProfile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 2)`